# How to make a java executable run in the background instead of the foreground?

Tags: java, macos, executable-jar

I wrote a shell script to run a set of experiments so I won't have to do it manually. The script runs a java .jar file 30 times, and runs a set of those 30 times 17 times changing a few variables in between.

I invoke the program like this:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/Users/me/Desktop/Cfiles/DynamicCTGLayout/build/Release  -jar [name of .jar file]
```

However, I can't do anything in parallel while the program runs because when this line is executed, the java executable pops out at the forefront of the screen. In essence when I work on something else it gets interrupted every 1-1.5 minutes. so I'm looking at a few hours I can't actually use the computer.

Is there a way to invoke an executable so that it doesn't pop out on top of all the other programs?

Sincerely,
WhiteTiger

Edit:
Basically I'm looking for the Mac OSX equivalent to Windows'

```
start /min java [arguments]
```

Comment: @Marcelo, I was almost going to point you to [this question on meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88046/is-58-accept-rate-bad) before I noticed the smiley! You got me. ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I prevent command line java processes from stealing focus in OSX?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911748/how-can-i-prevent-command-line-java-processes-from-stealing-focus-in-osx)

Answer (score 6):

Use `javaw` instead of `java` (you might need to make sure its on the path). This will run it without any console.

`javaw -Djava.library.path=/Users/me/Desktop/Cfiles/DynamicCTGLayout/build/Release  -jar [name of .jar file]`

Comment: thnx Femi, but not quite what I'm looking for

I mean I want the entire GUI of the program to pop in the background and the current program I'm working with to stay as "the currently selected program", if that makes sense

Comment: Oh: your question didn't say anything about the GUI, just the executable, which I (and others) assumed was the console. Bad question. In any case: are you using Swing? SWT? some other graphics toolkit?

Comment: @Femi `javaw` is not available on OSX

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem when executing a program encapsulated in a JAR. I fixed it by adding the option `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to my command line invocation (see [oracle docs](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911748/how-can-i-prevent-command-line-java-processes-from-stealing-focus-in-osx)). So, you would run:

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.library.path=/Users/me/Desktop/Cfiles/DynamicCTGLayout/build/Release -jar [name of .jar file]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in unix by adding `&` symbol at the end of the command line, it pushes a process to background

Comment: No, this is not wat he wants...he is annoyed because the (multiple times) started app steals his focus.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Linux (or an OS that uses X) cou could put a "fake" X server in place using Xvfb and set the DISPLAY variable for the JAVA app so that it uses this disaply. The downside: You can't access the GUI of the launched application (which is, to my understanding, not a problem in your case).

On one shell: `Xvfb :2`

On aother shell: `DISPLAY=:2 java -jar ...`

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you can use:

```
start /min java [parameters]
```

This will start the program minimized and not take focus away. I tested it successfully in Windows 7 Professional x64.

Comment: Okay, this is more in the direction of what I'm looking for...
What would be the command to do this on MacOSX?

Comment: Added untested solution for MacOSx

Comment: this also doesn't seem to work since I get an error saying 
    open: invalid option -- D  
referring to the option -Djava.library.path=/Users/borisshabash/Desktop/School/CMPT/894/jViz/Cfiles/DynamicCTGLayout/build/Release

even if I try without that option, the Terminal still loses focus and becomes deselected

Comment: I will remove that part from my answer and give up, because I really don't have an environment to test.