# How can I prevent command line java processes from stealing focus in OSX?

Tags: java, macos

Has anyone else noticed that their command line java applications in OSX create GUI processes that steal focus(ie, groovy, maven sub processes)? I'm finding it extremely annoying; probably b/c I've been living with it for like 6-8 months since I think OSX v10.6?

How can I prevent java processes from doing this in OSX?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Eventually I found the basic solution:

For Java applications in general you can specify that they are 'headless', by adding the option `-Djava.awt.headless=true` to your java application.

Comment: I found that the order mattered in my case. I was calling `java -jar /path/to/my.jar -Djava.awt.headless=true`. Changed to `java -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar /path/to/my.jar` and it fixed it.

`java version "1.8.0_72"`

`Darwin 15.0.0 Darwin Kernel Version 15.0.0: Sat Sep 19 15:53:46 PDT` `2015; root:xnu-3247.10.11~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64 i386`

Answer (score 2):

Add to your shell configuration, e.g., .bashrc:

export MAVEN_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true

Comment: this is not good enough, you need to pass it to sub processes in maven as well.