# What is ImageIO doing when reading a file?

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I am a bit confused by `ImageIO.read(file)`.  When I try to read a .png file into a BufferedImage, at least on macOS, the focus moves to a new application named after my main class.  It appears in the Menu bar.  It does so even when I run java from the command line.

[image]

The annoying thing is that it moves the focus out of my IDE and I have to return to it manually.

I looked at the source of `ImageIO.read(file)`.  I discovered that it is calling `ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file)` and that is what triggers this behaviour.

My question is: what is ImageIO doing actually,  why is my main class showing in the Menu bar when it is just loading information in memory.  And most important, how can I avoid it?

Below the code to show the problem.  Use any .png to test it.

```
package misc;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadImageTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("out/production/resources/picture.png");
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            ImageInputStream stream = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(file);
            long delay = System.currentTimeMillis() - time;
            System.out.println("stream: " + stream.length());
            System.out.println("time: " + delay/1000.0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Using Headless Mode in the Java SE Platform](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html) describes what is headless mode and how to use it properly.

> Headless mode is a system configuration in which the display device,
>   keyboard, or mouse is lacking. Sounds unexpected, but actually you can
>   perform different operations in this mode, even with graphic data.

You can enable it by adding below option to your program:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

See also:

- [What is the benefit of setting java.awt.headless=true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067235/what-is-the-benefit-of-setting-java-awt-headless-true)
- [How can I prevent command line java processes from stealing focus in OSX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911748/how-can-i-prevent-command-line-java-processes-from-stealing-focus-in-osx)
- [Setting java.awt.headless=true programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552371/setting-java-awt-headless-true-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks.  I just tried it, it works for me.  I am still curious why it is necessary in the first place.  There is no display involved in my example.

Comment: @FlorianF, I did not dig to much but I expect that `ImageIO` is one of the classes related with `AWT` which from other hand by default uses `UI`. So expectation is you need some `UI` features but your console app does not need `UI` and you need to instruct `AWT`: "Even so I am loading image I am not going to show it on display and I do not need `UI` features so do not take focus like for window app".